# Using C++/CLI In Visual Studio 2013

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-c++, visual-studio-2013, c++-cli

I'm trying to learn [C++/CLI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Managed_Extensions_for_C%2B%2B#Main_programmatic_changes_in_Managed_C.2B.2B).

I've tried this before in Visual Studio 2010 and it worked fine.

[image]

[image]

When I test this with Visual Studio 2013 / Update4 then I'm getting intellisense errors.

> Error : "#using" requires C++/CLI mode.

[image]

I've already set "Common Language Runtime support" of this project.

[image]

I did not understand what could be causing this problem.

Comment: Does the code still compile and run since the update?

Comment: I'm not tried before update.

Comment: it's working fine in visual studio 2010

Comment: What compile errors do you get with VS2013 update 4?

Comment: Error : "#using" requires C++/CLI mode.

Comment: That looks like the intellisense error, delete the local "sdf" and ipch files etc. and try to open the project again. What is the error code the compiler gives you?

Comment: I tried to delete ManagedExtensionCpp.sdf and ipch directory.Error is still

Comment: Why not different vs 2013 intellisense error message from vs 2010 ?

Comment: Have you changed the `/clr` support for both the release and debug modes? From the screen shot it looks like you might not have changed it for the currently active mode. Make sure you change it for all the configurations.

Comment: problem solved :) thanks you very much@Niall

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Intellisense problems can stem from a few issues.

First thing to check is remove local "sdf" and "ipch" files and directories. The newer versions of VS are much better at keeping these from being corrupted, but it never hurts to rebuild these as they are temporary files anyway.

Second is to check that the configuration being "viewed" is correctly configured (in this case with `/clr`). In general is best to be consistent with this setting over the debug and release versions of the project.

Answer (score 3):

VS2013 has an excessively annoying bug that has cost me many head-hairs and I don't have that many to spare.  This bug is also present in VS2015 RTM which made it worse, now also presenting a Platform that isn't actually part of your solution (Win32 when x86 is the valid one).  VS2015 Update 1 finally did something about it.

When you use Project > Properties then it has a knack for showing the wrong configuration.  Like it did here, you are editing settings for the Release configuration while Debug is the active configuration.  I never discovered a pattern to this bug, little you can do about this but *always* eagle-eye the comboboxes on the top of the dialog to ensure you got the right one.

And specific in this case, never forget to make such a change in *all* configurations or you'll lose an hour of your life trying to get the Release build to work when you have no time to spare anymore.